# JQuery Sortable post - mismatched items

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am a bit puzzled why this is happening. I am posting a list of data from a JQuery sortable list to the default model binder (MVC). When I inspect the html just before I post, it shows 2 items ready to be posted which is correct.

[image]

When I inspect what the modelbinder is receiving, there are 3 items!

[image]

And, yes, I am aware that the indexes are not starting at 0 (I removed the first item). Does this have an effect?

Comment: According to a few posts, the index must be 0 based and sequential. This is most probably causing the issues. Means that I have to re-index all the controls in the list when one is removed.

Answer (score 0):

OK - well there are probably other ways to do this but it is now doing what I want. On the receive and remove events of the Sortable list, I call this function to write up new hidden items. That way, the ModelBinder is happy - and therefore, so am I.

```
function AddHiddenItems() {
    // clear out the items every time an item is added or removed
    $("#skills").find(":hidden").remove();
    $("#skills li").each(function (index) {
        $('#skills').append('<input type="hidden" name="Contract.Skills[' + index + '].SkillId" value=' + $(this).attr("id") + ' />');
        $('#skills').append('<input type="hidden" name="Contract.Skills[' + index + '].SkillDescription" value=' + $(this).text() + ' />');
    });
}
```